# Out of memory error when trying to build a webpage from php with a lot of images

Tags: php, html, image, performance

I ran into an interesting (well at least in my opinion) problem.

I have a PHP script that should generate the formatting (eg. the absolute positioning values of each image so they get displayed next to each other in a logical pattern) and the image sources when run. When completed it would load the appropriate image path from an sql db but currently I have a problem with this at this point.

Currently my script looks something like:

```
for ($i=0; $i<(866+1+866); $i++){
        for ($j=0; $j<1001; $j++){
            $data .= "<div id=\"tac-".$j."\"><img src=\"default_tactical.png\"/></div>";
        }
    }
```

As you can see it's rather basic at this point, as I only wanted to test if I can get the images in place.

Also the `$data` is a variable that my template simply `echo`-es to the browser.

The problem with all this is that my server runs out-of memory whenever I try to run this script.

So what's the problem? Or rather: how can I have a lot of images in a webpage without running out of memory?

Comment: `echo` each `<div>` instead of building a giant string and then printing it. Better yet, don't make 1,000,000 image tags in the first place. Why don't you use CSS and tile a background image?

Comment: What everyone else said - echo them in the for loop. Otherwise you are concatenating 1.7 million `divs` and `img` tags into a single massive string (which is why you're running out of memory) and then telling the browser to render all of them at once.  Also, why would you possibly need 1.7 million images on the page in the first place?

Comment: According to apache error log, the error occurs on the line with the `$data .= "...`.

Comment: Yes that's because you are building a MASSIVE string in memory as the for loops iterate... every single time someone requests the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing it to:

```
for ($i=0; $i<(866+1+866); $i++){
        for ($j=0; $j<1001; $j++){
            echo "<div id=\"tac-".$j."\"><img src=\"default_tactical.png\"/></div>";
        }
    }
```

It should not run out of memory since it's not storing anything, just directly outputs it.

**EDIT**: Since you can't modify the code, just try raising the memory limit somewhere in the code (can be any PHP code that is executed before your loop).

```
@ini_set("memory_limit", "512M");
```

Comment: Good for an idea, but it would require a rewrite of the (kinda makeshift) framework that gives the overall look of the page.

Answer (score 1):

Look at it this way, you've got 2 nested loop, and are building a string inside.

```
866+1+66 = 1733 x 1002 = 17,364,66 iterations

17,364,666 iterations * 40 chars = ~70 megabytes
```

Either DON'T build the string at all once, or at least split it into chunks, e.g.

```
for ($i = ....) {
   for ($j = ....) {
      ... build string here
   }
   echo $string
   $string = ''; // reset to empty string and start over
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While you haven't echo your `$data`, you haven't load image, it's just a string. It's the navigator which going to load each image after PHP processing. **Your PHP is executed in the server and client load images.** It's your variable $data which is out of memory.

Try like this :

```
for ($i=0; $i<(866+1+866); $i++){
        for ($j=0; $j<1001; $j++){
            echo "<div id=\"tac-".$j."\"><img src=\"default_tactical.png\"/></div>";
        }
    }
```